# How to Include com.questoid.sqlitemanager_1.0.0 jar file in ANDROID STUDIO?? please help on this

Tags: android-studio

> How to Include  com.questoid.sqlitemanager_1.0.0 jar 
>   file in ANDROID STUDIO?? please help on this

Answer (score 0):

Put it in the folder libs of your app and you have to verify into the builde.gradle the dependecies:

```
    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```